# How to write Safari(5) specific CSS?

Tags: css, safari

I would like to know how can I create a CSS file specific to safari(5)or less.

Comment: You need to give more detail. Are you talking about browser specific prefix to css attribute, or how to generally create a css file?

Comment: I have an issue with CSS.It works on all browsers except safari.so I would like to know if there is any way to write a specific css file to target Safari just like we do for IE.

Comment: This sounds like a typical XY Problem, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You should ask how to solve the "issue with CSS" [you're having](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), not how to apply CSS to only Safari.

Comment: I think your only real option will be to use JavaScript and try to use browser detection and load the desired CSS file.  And as most people will tell you, browser detection is a poor solution to anything because browsers are easily spoofed or do not set their values properly.  But I do enjoy Pierre-Alain Vigeant's idea.   But I agree with joar and thirtydot.  Tell us what your problem is, we can help you find a solution.  I suspect that there's a better solution if it's Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have some CSS code that execute for Safari and Chrome, you have to check for the `-webkit-` prefix

[This is an example](http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php?pid=20) of such CSS that will only apply when the browser is Safari or any browser that understand the `-webkit-` prefix

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) 
{ 
    #safari { display: block; }
}
```

Just a reminder, this is not a fail-safe solution.

Comment: That's clearly also going to be applied in Chrome. Maybe the OP wants this, and has just been unclear, but it's not a good idea to assume so.

Comment: I'm using a web font and importing it to the css with @font-face 

All browsers except safari renders it properly when font-weight is set to bold while in safari,the fonts super bold.I thought of setting font-weight to normal just for safari to see if it renders properly.

Comment: Have you tried setting font-weight to a number (e.g. 400 for normal, 600 for bold) instead of "bold"?

Comment: FYI my version of chrome (Version 23.0.1271.101) has implemented this. Even the webkit prefix ;o So no dice ...